# What is the probability of the second card being red after we know that the first card is not a heart ??

Tags: probability

I have a hard time understanding this simple question!!
From a deck of 52 cards. Two cards are drawn randomly, one at a time without replacement. What is the probability of the second card being red after we know that the first card is not a heart ??

Comment: The solution can change if you re insert the first card or not in the deck. Also you have to specify which deck it is...in Italy we have 40 cards decks too. so pleas for the future try to write the complete exercise....and what you tried too...

Comment: the first card not being (or being) a heart, does not give any information about the color ..

Comment: @tommik I have changed the question.

Comment: @GCab; so the question is wrong?

Comment: @GCab : the knowledge of the fact that "the first card is not a heart" gives us information about how many red cards are still in the deck. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Second card is Red}|\text{ First card is not Heart}]=$$

$$=\frac{\mathbb{P}[\text{Second card is Red}\cap\text{ First card is not Heart}]}{\mathbb{P}[\text{ First card is not Heart}]}=$$

$$=\frac{\frac{13}{52}\times \frac{25}{51}+\frac{26}{52}\times \frac{26}{51}}{\frac{39}{52}}\approx 0.5033$$

Comment: how is P[Second card is Red∩ First card is not Heart] calculated, also Thank you for your response.

Comment: @R.jan using the Total probability theorem:

$$\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{25}{51}+\frac{26}{52}\cdot\frac{26}{51}$$

where

 $\frac{13}{52}$ is the probability to get a diamond at first draw

and  $\frac{25}{51}$ is the probability to get a red card given that I draw a diamond first (always a red card). The rest is similar

Answer (score 2):

Let the probability you seek be denoted by $P$. Here is a geometric argument:

1. Assume that the first card was red. Then you have $p_1 := \dfrac{25}{51}$ probability of picking a red card on the second go. One would expect $p_1 < P$.
2. Assume the first card was black. Then the probability of picking a red card on the second choice is $p_2 := \dfrac{26}{51}$. The expectation is that $P < p_2$.

As the first card was **not** hearts (which is red), we would expect $P$ to be $\dfrac{2}{3}$ the way from $p_1$ to $p_2$. So:

\begin{align}
P &= p_1 + \dfrac{2}{3} (p_2 - p_1) =\\
  &= \dfrac{25}{51} + \dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{51} =\\
  &= \dfrac{77}{153} \approx 0.50327.
\end{align}

**Edit *(response to comment)***

The $\dfrac{2}{3}$ is essentially a weight on assumption 2 while $\dfrac{1}{3}$ is the weight on assumption 1 ***given*** that the first card is *not* hearts. If hearts is ruled out, there are $3$ remaining possible classes of cards. Two of these are black; hence the weight $\dfrac{2}{3}$. Note that you could also write

$$P = \dfrac{1}{3}p_1 + \dfrac{2}{3}p_2$$

to, of course, arrive at the same end result.

Comment: thanks I like this approach; I understand the 2 cases but could you explain more on P to be 2/3 ?

Comment: @R.jan I have added more information to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am denoting the events in which 1st card is diamond or (spade or club) as A,B respectively. 
P(A)=$\frac{1}{4}$ , P(B)=$\frac{1}{2}$ 
denoting the event in which 2nd card is red as C 
P$\left(\frac{C}{A}\right)$=$\frac{25}{51}$ 
P$\left(\frac{C}{B}\right)$=$\frac{26}{51}$ 
P(C∩(A∪B))=$\frac{1}{4}$×$\frac{25}{51}$+$\frac{1}{2}$
×$\frac{26}{51}$  
P($\frac{C}{A∪B})$ =$\frac{\frac{1}{4}×\frac{25}{51}+\frac{1}{2}
×\frac{26}{51}}{{\frac{3}{4}}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$P\left(R_{2}\cap H_{1}^{c}\right)=P\left(R_{2}\right)-P\left(R_{2}\cap H_{1}\right)=P\left(R_{2}\right)-P\left(R_{2}\mid H_{1}\right)P\left(H_{1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{25}{51}\frac{1}{4}$$

So that:

$$P\left(R_{2}\mid H_{1}^{c}\right)=\frac{P\left(R_{2}\cap H_{1}^{c}\right)}{P\left(H_{1}^{c}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{25}{51}\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{77}{153}\approx0.503268$$